# Aurelia not transpiling Set and Spread operator correctly

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to produce a unique list of group names from some json data using aurelia. The code works using plain javascript in Chrome but throws an error when running in Aurelia. See Fiddle.

The error I'm getting is 'concat is not a function'. It appears to be an issue with babel or webpack. The code below is the transpiled version I'm seeing in the browser.

```
var groupList = new Set(jsonData.map(function (x) {
  return x.group.name;
})).concat(); //concat is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
let jsonData = [
  { index: '0', name: 'INCH', factor: '12', desc: '', magnitude: '1', group: {name: 'length'} },
  { index: '1', name: 'FOOT', factor: '3', desc: '', magnitude: '2', group: {name: 'length'} },
  { index: '2', name: 'YARD', factor: '3', desc: '', magnitude: '3', group: {name: 'length'} },
  { index: '6', name: 'SQ FOOT', factor: '3', desc: '', magnitude: '2', group: {name: 'area'} },
  { index: '7', name: 'SQ YARD', factor: '3', desc: '', magnitude: '3', group: {name: 'area'} }
];

createGroups();

function createGroups() {
  const groupList = [...new Set(jsonData.map(x => x.group.name))];
  debugger;
}
```

If I plug in the code below in at Babel's website it produces completely different code than what I'm getting from Aurelia. Thought maybe I had an old version of Babel so I updated to the latest version but still getting the same error. Is there any work around or solution?

```
const groupList = [...new Set(jsonData.map(x => x.group.name))];
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisevich/e1v9rpg2/96/

Comment: How are you building your Aurelia application? Are you using the CLI? If so, what version of the CLI?

Comment: Yes using CLI ver 5.8.0

Comment: Our CLI is currently at 1.0.0-beta.7. There is no version 5.8.0 of the Aurelia CLI

Comment: If package.sjon is the correct place to find the version: "aurelia-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.7"

Comment: This is a bug in the babel config for the current version of the CLI, most likely. Please file a bug report here: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/new

Comment: It looks like it is related to this bug report, and the fact that our babel config uses `loose: true`. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7958

Comment: Yeah, we should not use `loose: true` in the default config. I'll file an issue for you.

Comment: Issue filed here: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/1000

Comment: loose mode has benefit on both performance and size, that's why aurelia-cli were using loose mode since the beginning. Alternatively you can still use loose mode with `const groupList = Array.from(new Set(jsonData.map(x => x.group.name)));`

Answer (score 1):

Setting `'loose': false` in `babelrc.js` fixes the problem.